# Calling this in a Javascript function called by innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm creating a Windows 7 gadget and allowing a user to log-in through the gadget.  The gadget will be logging into any valid (as defined by the application domain) address the user provides.  Now here I am running into a problem.  I do something like this:

```
function Object(address){  
   this.address = address
 ....
this.loginBox = gDocument.createElement("loginBox");
this.loginBox.innerHTML = "<FORM name = 'myForm' action='' method='GET'><input type='text' name='usernameBox' id = 'usernameBox' VALUE=''><input type='password' id = 'passwordBox'><button type = 'button' value = 'Ok' id = 'loginButton' onclick='login()'></FORM>";
```

(Note: If anyone could format the above code that would be nice but it's not necessary to know exactly what's going on just to know the concept of what I'm trying to do)

So in login I cannot do this.address to get the address because the address is held in each object.  The login method is not technically part of the prototype.  If it were, I wouldn't know how to call it from the HTML.  (Well, that's not true, I would know how to call it, but I would only know how to call it as a prototype method, where it would execute the functionality but not have any of the local variables).

Any help with getting the login method that is called by myForm to know of the local variables would be greatly appreciated.  The variable I want to get is this.address.  The login function is simply function login.

Comment: Mybe you need to include more of the code... what local variable (local where) do you want to capture in the login method?

Comment: I tried to make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is render the form to the document, lookup the button by the id and attach the event with attachEvent so you can control the scope.

```
this.loginBox = gDocument.createElement("loginBox");
this.loginBox.innerHTML = "<FORM name = 'myForm' action='' method='GET'><input type='text' name='usernameBox' id = 'usernameBox' VALUE=''><input type='password' id = 'passwordBox'><button type = 'button' value = 'Ok' id = 'loginButton'></FORM>"

// add this.loginBox to the document here

// Look up the button in the document and add the click handler
var button = gDocument.getElementById('loginButton');
button.attachEvent('onclick', this.login);
```

you may have to do something to bind the scope, can't remember.

```
var $this = this;
button.attachEvent('onclick', function() {
  $this.login.apply($this, arguments);
});
```

Comment: I tried using your code and I get a runtime error: "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Comment: which line, getElementById or attachEvent?

Comment: attachEvent.  I tried using both different solutions.  I also tried setting button.onclick = this.login;  That doesn't give me an error but it also doesn't function, and when that is set clicking the button keeps it held down, it doesn't get released until clicking somewhere else.

Comment: try `button.onclick = function() { $this.login.apply($this, arguments); return true; }` Something weird with the IE embedded for gadgets, because attachEvent works just fine in IE normally.

Comment: That doesn't give me an error and the button clicks normally.  However, it doesn't seem to work...  The first thing I do in login is throw debugger; and I don't hit the debugger so that's how I assume it doesn't work...

Comment: Wanna keep tryin'? Put the debugger statement in that lambda function. before the call to login.

Comment: I tried putting the debugger there and all it did was tell me the object didn't support the property or method.  (The apply property is what I assume it's referring to).  I can make attaching the event work if I define the function inside of the function instead of making it a call to something, but it's pretty messy.

Comment: The debugger did launch? You can use the console to see if $this is defined. It seems more likely that `$this.login` is undefined, null, or jscript thinks it's an object instead of a function. If this keeps up, I may have to boot into windows.

Comment: $this is defined.  You are correct however, apparently it thinks $this.login is an object.

Comment: Wow I just realized I'm an idiot and I had a graphical component also called login at another point in this script that was causing the confusion. It's a very long script so it was just something that slipped my mind. Sorry for putting you through this, your onclick solution works now. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the "dirty" way is just passing the address to the function like this:

```
this.loginBox.innerHTML = "<FORM ....  id = 'loginButton' onclick='login(\"" + this.address + "\");'>Login</button></FORM>";
```

The elegant way will be doing as Hemlock suggested but as I've no idea what is `gDocument` I'm not sure it support the required methods.

Comment: This ended up working, thank you.  I agree that it's a dirty way of doing it but it's the only way it seems to work.

Comment: @user535617 glad it's working.. can you explain what is `gDocument` or post some link? Maybe there is other way, so it's worth a try. :)